# Flutter: Override 'PageView' scroll gesture with child's GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a combination of `BottomNavigationBar` and `PageView` for navigation in my app. The user can either swipe to the next page or use the navigation bar.

On one of my pages, I would like to use a gesture detector that handles pan gestures, both vertically and horizontally.

I can't find a way to override PageView's gesture detection with the nested GestureDetector. This means only vertical pan gestures are handled, as the horizontal ones are occupied by the PageView.

**How can I disable/override the PageViews gesture detection for only that page or only the widget, without completely disabling the PageViews scroll physics?**

I have created a simplified version of my App to isolate the issue, and attached a video of the problem below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: 'GestureDetector' only recieves vertical drag gestures...]

Here is the code inside my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: GestureIssueExample(),
    );
  }
}

class GestureIssueExample extends StatefulWidget {
  GestureIssueExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GestureIssueExampleState createState() => _GestureIssueExampleState();
}

class _GestureIssueExampleState extends State<GestureIssueExample> {
  int _navigationIndex;
  double _xLocalValue;
  double _yLocalValue;
  PageController _pageController;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onNavigationPageChanged,
        children: [
          //Just a placeholder to represent a page to the left of the "swipe cards" widget
          _buildSamplePage("Home"),

          //Center child of 'PageView', contains a GestureDetector that handles Pan Gestures
          //Thanks to the page view however, only vertical pan gestures are detected, while both horizontal and vertical gestures
          //need to be handled...
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                    "Local X: ${_xLocalValue.toString()}\nLocal Y: ${_yLocalValue.toString()}"),
                GestureDetector(
                  onPanStart: (details) => setState(
                    () {
                      this._xLocalValue = details.localPosition.dx;
                      this._yLocalValue = details.localPosition.dy;
                    },
                  ),
                  onPanUpdate: (details) => setState(
                    () {
                      this._xLocalValue = details.localPosition.dx;
                      this._yLocalValue = details.localPosition.dy;
                    },
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Slidable Surface",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //Just a placeholder to represent a page to the right of the "swipe cards" widget
          _buildSamplePage("Settings"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this._navigationIndex = 0;
    this._pageController = PageController(
      initialPage: _navigationIndex,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSamplePage(String text) {
    // This simply returns a container that fills the page,
    // with a text widget in its center.

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.grey[900],
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    //Returns the bottom navigation bar for the scaffold
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: "Home"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank), label: "Cards"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined), label: "Settings"),
      ],
      currentIndex: _navigationIndex,
      onTap: _onNavigationPageChanged,
    );
  }

  void _onNavigationPageChanged(int newIndex) {
    //Set the new navigation index for the nav bar
    setState(() => this._navigationIndex = newIndex);

    //Animate to the selected page
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      newIndex,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      duration: Duration(microseconds: 100),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

Add this line to your `PageView`:

```dart
PageView(
...
physics: _navigationIndex == 1 ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
...
)
```

Note: the number `1` is because the page with the `GestureDetector` is on index `1`.

Comment: Hello Andrej, thank you for your answer! I have tried that solution, but unfortunately it causes a different issue. The PageViews "currentIndex" updates when the new page enters the center of the screen. This causes swiping to the center page (index 1) to stop as soon as the page passes the center of the screen, resulting in the UI beeing stuck between the two pages. Please let me know if I can provide any more information!

Comment: I just tried it on my phone and it worked fine. Please check out the recording: https://www.screencast.com/t/U9J0dXSYib, can you add another screen recording of the new issue?

Comment: Hey Andrey, no need for that.. I just realized the reason the solution you suggested wasn't working was because the PageView in my original App was using a different index variable, that was not beeing updated correctly when I set the state. I tried your solution in both my test app and properly in the real version, and both are now working fine. Thank you very much for your help!